# Does crashpad_handler in the task manager mean that r is frozen?

Tags: r, rstudio, freeze

I am running R Studio and see that the R Session is still running and it utilizing cpu, but I also see something call crashpad_handler (I can take a picture if that would help). The program I am running should take a while but I'm worried that the program may have caused R Studio to freeze. If crashpad_handler shows up on the task manager, does that mean that R studio is frozen? Or is crashpad_handler just a safeguard in case the R Studio crashes?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: No, but I solved it by including process bars. If the progress bar stalls, then I assume that R Studio has crashed.